# How can I pass variable from one activity to another without device crashing for NPE?

Tags: java, android

I have the following in my code but my app keeps on crashing.

MainActivity:

```
 new Intent(context, RetrieveInfoActivity.class).putExtra("Interval",  interval);
```

RetrieveInfoActivity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent (context, MainActivity.class);
Long intervalAlarm = intent.getExtras().getLong("Interval"); //I keep getting an NPE here.
```

I think I might know why, since I am doing this in onCreate(), it's trying to grab the value before the alarm is set/interval is set from MainActivity. I was wondering how can I make it so it doesn't grab the value when the interval is not set/not null?

EDIT:

I have this in my onCreate() and now it never gets called even though it should. Should I be setting this somewhere else?

```
 if (getIntent().getExtras()!= null) {

            intervalAlarm = getIntent().getExtras().getLong("Interval");
            System.out.println("Interval: " + intervalAlarm);
        }
```

EDIT: This method is called in doInBackground in an Async Task!

```
private void setAlarms() {

            AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

            interval = 900000L;

            try {

            .....

                    new Intent(context, RetrieveInfoActivity.class).putExtra("PendingIntent",  pendingIntent);
                    new Intent(context, RetrieveInfoActivity.class).putExtra("Interval",  interval);
                    //Set Alarm to Repeat
                    manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeInMilis, interval, pendingIntent);
                     new Intent(context, Time.class);

                //Instantiates the intent to launch a new activity
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, RetrieveInfoActivity.class);
                MainActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);

            }
            catch(ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

inside `RetrieveInfoActivity` you should use

```
long intervalAlarm = getIntent().getExtras().getLong("Interval");
```

instead of

```
Intent intent = new Intent (context, MainActivity.class);
Long intervalAlarm = intent.getExtras().getLong("Interval");
```

Edit.

In your code you should create just one intent and fill it up with the information you want to provide to the new Activity.  E.g.

```
Intent intent =new Intent(MainActivity.this, RetrieveInfoActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("PendingIntent", pendingIntent);   
intent.putExtra("Interval", interval);  
MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: +1. You should also check if `extras` are not `null`.

Comment: The strange thing is even when I set my interval in my MainActivity, when I pass it to RetrieveInfo.. It's 0? It should be a numerical value.

Comment: Please see my edit. It seems like because on create it's set to null all the time even though I do set it a numerical value in MainActivity. very strange.

Comment: Post the place where you start RetrieveInfoActivity

Comment: Where I start it where? In my MainActivity or onCreate retrieveInfo?

Comment: in MainActivity .. Where you do create the intent and call startActivity

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64655/discussion-between-euridice01-and-blackbelt).

Comment: I am on mobile now. Let's talk about it tomorrow

Comment: ok thanks but I think it's because all activities are set up in oncreate before main activity background process is finished?

Answer (score 0):

In your MainActivity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, RetrieveInfoActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("Interval", interval);
startActivity(intent);
```

In your RetrieveInfoActivity:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
if (intent.getExtras() != null) {
    intervalAlarm = intent.getLongExtra("Interval", 0); // 0 is default value
}
```